# How to set jenkins log level from maven?

Tags: jenkins, java.util.logging

I am running Jenkins from source using `mvn jenkins-dev:run`. It seems to be logging at the DEBUG level making page load very slow. How do I change the log level of Jenkins. I have tried the usual util.logging properties file, but I can't get it working.

Answer (score 2):

`mvn jenkins-dev:run -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=error`

> Default log level for all instances of SimpleLogger. Must be one of ("trace", "debug", "info", "warn", or "error"). If not specified, defaults to "info".

You can also edit `${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties` to make it consistent.

More info here: http://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

**EDIT:**

To also control the log level of the Jenkins `war` itself as the OP wanted i was able to do so using:

```
mvn jenkins-dev:run -Djava.util.logging.config.file=my-logging.properties
```

The contents of `my-logging.properties` are:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= SEVERE
```

Now i only see two `INFO` messages comming from `jetty` . One could also configure the `jetty` logger via the same file if needed, i will not go into more detail about how to do this because i have little experience with it, but if i could take a guess, you would have to manipulate the correct class (eg: `org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN`) used by Jenkins when embedding `jetty`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. I am not trying to change logging for maven. The above command starts a java process that run the Jenkins war file. I want to change the logging used by that. It seems that Jenkins is using java.utill.logging with DEBUG level by default.https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/compare/ba93862659b2...5e2b15426118 Seems to be causing issue.

Comment: I have edited the answer, sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Hi Nicolae, this is not working. I have tried with `java -jar jenkins.war -D...` too. No luck there, too. Here is a log sample: 01:58:52.542 [Handling POST /ajaxBuildQueue from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 : RequestHandlerThread[#5]] DEBUG o.apache.commons.jelly.JellyContext - Registering tag library to: jelly:swt taglib: org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.swt.SwtTagLibrary
01:58:52.542 [Handling POST /ajaxBuildQueue from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 : RequestHandlerThread[#5]] DEBUG o.apache.commons.jelly.JellyContext - Registering tag library to: jelly:swt taglib: org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.swt.SwtTagLibrary

Comment: I am out of options, maybe you should wait for https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19352 to be released, and try that